# Web API Service - How to make the requests at the server to be executed concurrently

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, session-state

I am using a WebApi rest service controller, hosted by IIS 7.5,
as i understood from this post:

[Are all the web requests executed in parallel and handled asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845639/are-all-the-web-requests-executed-in-parallel-and-handled-asynchronously)

A **webApi** service, by default, executes all its incoming requests in parallel, **but only** if the **current multiple requests** (at a certain time) came from **different sessions.**
That is to say, if single client will send some **simultaneously** requests to server, all of them will be executed **sequentially** and won't be **executed concurrently**.

This behavior is a real **problem** for us, because in some cases, our client sends bunch of requests from different client's listeners, asynchronously (by browser), and all of them will actually be **queued** instead of being **executed concurrently** at the server. Therefore, in some cases, we experiencing a **serious performance issues** which are really noticeable at the client's web page.

How can we solve this problem?
I understand we can maybe  **disable session state** but that isn't a normal thing to do.

Comment: Have you seen an `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie being created? Is this a pure Web API project or are you using an `ApiController` in an MVC application?

Comment: I'm using ApiController, which implements 'Post' method, and that's the method i'm accessing from my client browser by $.ajax command. Where can i see if 'ASP.NET_SessionId' cookie had been created for sure? at our chrome browser, in "Resources" at the developer tools panel, I've noticed we have a record of this cookie.

Comment: It's totally reasonable to disable session state if you don't use it.  In fact, I disable it for several of my load balanced applications and use cookies to store preferences and other data which isn't secure in nature.  Everything else is loaded when required.

Comment: The Web Browser limits the number of concurrent requests to a single domain too, so you might be seeing that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Comment: It is not entirely accurate what you say about the default behavior of a WebApi service with regard to the ASP.NET Session State. Like @Stijn suggests, it's important to make a difference (to avoid confusion) between using and ApiController in an MVC.NET application on one hand, and a "pure" WebApi application on the other. In the latter, by default there is no session state, hence all requests execute in parallel (with other limitations applied). A read/write session state will be "blocking" as would any other "locking" resource.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, disabling session state is the *normal* solution for web APIs. If you need it for some/all of your calls, you can call [HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.setsessionstatebehavior.aspx) (e.g., from `Application_BeginRequest`). Multiple read-only session state requests can run concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Do you try async Task ? Here is sample Controller:

```
public class SendJobController : ApiController
    {
        public async Task<ResponseEntity<SendJobResponse>> Post([FromBody] SendJobRequest request)
        {
            return await PostAsync(request);
        }

        private async Task<ResponseEntity<SendJobResponse>> PostAsync(SendJobRequest request)
        {
            Task<ResponseEntity<SendJobResponse>> t = new Task<ResponseEntity<SendJobResponse>>(() =>
            {
                ResponseEntity<SendJobResponse> _response = new ResponseEntity<SendJobResponse>();

                try
                {
                    //  
                    // some long process
                    // 
                    _response.responseStatus = "OK"; 
                    _response.responseMessage = "Success";
                    _response.responseObject = new SendJobResponse() { JobId = 1 };

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _response.responseStatus = "ERROR"; 
                    _response.responseMessage = ex.Message;
                }

                return _response;
            });

            t.Start();
            return await t;
        }
    }
```