# How to create async web-api controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, async-await

(based on my other [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736034/why-is-this-web-api-controller-not-concurrent))

I have created the following async web-api-controller action, but it never returns

```
public async Task<string> Tester()
{
    Task t = new Task(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));

    await t;

    return "OK";
}
```

what am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It never returns because the task was never started, so it hangs. Call the `Task.Start` method:

```
Task t = new Task(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));
t.Start();
```

*Or* use `Task.Run` instead:

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));
```

*Or* use `Task.Delay` instead which is non-blocking (unless you used `Thread.Sleep` just for the sake of an example):

```
Task t = Task.Delay(2000);
```

Bear in mind that in a web application, *everything* except I/O-bound work should be synchronous. Deferring CPU-bound work to the thread pool won't buy you anything - if anything, it'll hurt performance.

See Stephen Cleary's [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

Comment: @EladKatz Yes, it is. DB access often benefits from being async.

Comment: I'm using fiddler to run it 10 times simultaneously, yet it returns after 2,4,6,,20 seconds respectively. why? why is it still sequential?

Comment: @EladKatz you don't need async to be able to handle multiple requests simultaneously. If your requests are being handled sequentially, then your issue lies somewhere else. Seems like a config issue, maybe on IIS or Web.config, I dunno, I've never seen that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it in console application and it worked!

What you only need to do is to start the task t:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = Tester().Result;
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }

    public static async Task<string> Tester()
    {
        Task t = new Task(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000));
        t.Start();
        await t;

        return "OK";
    }
```