# Why are ASP.NET Web Api requests with basic auth not handled concurrently?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

I am using ASP.NET Web Api with basic authentication.

My problem is that multiple API calls are not handled concurrently.

Let's say we call this simple method multiple times from a single machine with the same user credentials. If you run it 5 times in one second, the overall processing time will be 25 seconds instead of 5.

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Authorize(Roles = @"domain\group")]
    public string Test()
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        var endTime = DateTime.Now;
        return $"{startTime} {endTime}";
    }
```

The answers to this question didn't help me:

- [c# - Why is this web api controller not concurrent? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736034/why-is-this-web-api-controller-not-concurrent)

I think it is because of the basic authentication.

I also tried changing the test method to `async` like this:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Authorize(Roles = @"domain\group")]
    public async Task<string> Test()
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        await Task.Run(() => {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        });
        var endTime = DateTime.Now;
        return $"{startTime} {endTime}";
    }
```

I also tried coloring the `ApiController` with `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]`.

How can I achieve concurrent calls? Or should I change authentication to something else (must be connected to AD groups!)?

Comment: _"Answers to Why is this web api controller not concurrent? doesn't seem to help me"_ - why not? Did you disable sessions?

Comment: `My problem is that API calls are not concurrent.` How did you come to that conclusion? Where is the API being called from?

Comment: @CodeCaster - I added to my web.config <sessionState mode="Off"/> without success.

Comment: @mjwills API is called from local browser. If I call 2 requests at once I see, that startTime of 2nd request = endTime of 1st. On the other hand if I call one reqest from mozilla and 1 from chrome at once, they are processed concurrently.

Comment: Could you perhaps be running into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser ? How are you doing the local requests? Through AJAX? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

@mjwills pointed me to the right direction. Code is perfectly OK. Problem was running concurrent requests from Chrome. When I wrote simple C# test application everything worked as expected.