# Owin WebAPI Max Concurrent Connections

Tags: asp.net-web-api, concurrency, owin, self-hosting

```
public IHttpActionResult TestSpeed()
{
     Sleep(10000);
}
```

Called the above API concurrently, I can only manage to squeeze approximately 16 connections within 12 seconds. I think this is kinda low.

Is there any hard cap concurrent limit in Owin WebAPI Selfhost?

**async** is not an option for now, since it requires me to change hell lot of existing codes.

Comment: There are many interesting answers here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736034/why-is-this-web-api-controller-not-concurrent