# Clarification on thread pool max threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, threadpool

I've read [*here*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx) that :

> In v2.0, 3.5, and 4.0, ASP.NET *initializes* the CLR ThreadPool with **100 threads per processor(core)**

That is correct  , I checked it (*I have 8 core machine , so 8*100 = 800*):

[image]

But then I saw [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630693/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-threads-available-in-asp-net-threadpool)  and [*this*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> maxWorkerThreads — Configures the maximum number of worker threads to
>   use for the process on a per-CPU basis.The range for this attribute is
>   from `5 through 100.` The default is `20`.

**Question**

I don't see how the numbers fits in here :

The first paragraph states that I have *max 100  threads per core* ( the image prove it , I have 8 cores).

But the second paragraph states that *the default maximum worker threads per core* is 20. So  if I have 8 cores then I must have 8*20 = 160 max threads.  *not* 800.

Can someone please shed  light?

**Update:**

I just found a way to get the key element value via c# code :

[image]

So now the number are fit in ,but still -  [*MSDN say the default is 20 ,  not 100*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.processmodelsection.maxworkerthreads%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[image]

And then they do mention 100  :

[image]

**What** is going on here?

Comment: You are confusing ThreadPool threads and ASP.NET worker threads. And as a curiosity it's OK but for all practical applications: When you ask about the max number of threads you're already doing something wrong. The number of worker threads is more the domain of the Server admin than that of the developer.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Aren't they're the same ? asp.net uses threadpool threads which are the worker threads

Comment: Yes, the worker threads are a subset. Their ceiling can be a useful tool for server resource management.  The Threadpool limit is an arbitrary high number that never should be reached.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Can you explain it further more with a deeper explanations.

Comment: Good question, I've spend a day reading articles and trying to understand hot IIS works. Could it be that `maxWorkerThreads` setting default value for `autoConfig` depends on IIS version? When I run my app under IIS Express 8 the value is around 4K and when I run it under IIS 8.5 on windows 8.1 the value is around 32K.

Comment: Seems like my assumption is correct. I've tried to change `maxWorkerThreads` to value `20` and the `workerThreads` value on thread pool under IIS 8.5 has changed to `80`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have looked at source code and have found that default value for `MaxWorkerThreads` is set to 100

```
private static readonly ConfigurationProperty _propMaxWorkerThreads = new ConfigurationProperty("maxWorkerThreads", typeof (int), (object) 100, (TypeConverter) null, (ConfigurationValidatorBase) new IntegerValidator(1, 2147483646), ConfigurationPropertyOptions.None);
```

This field is added to properties collection in static constructor

```
ProcessModelSection._properties.Add(ProcessModelSection._propMaxWorkerThreads);
```

In property definition they do set default value to 20

```
[IntegerValidator(MaxValue = 2147483646, MinValue = 1)]
[ConfigurationProperty("maxWorkerThreads", DefaultValue = 20)]
public int MaxWorkerThreads
```

But this obviously give no effect. Maybe it's some kind of legacy implementation. By the way it behaves this way only if `autoConfig` is set to false. When it's set to true I have 32K worker threads in my application. Probably this behavior depends on IIS version.

Comment: So the docs are old updated via attribute and not via property ?

Comment: Could be, I actually have no idea.

Comment: p.s this whole uqestion came from this [book  chapter which I read](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=aIs8drBVdaoC&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=%22For+the+tests+below+to+work+as+I+describe,+use+Windows+Server+2008+or+2008+R2%22&source=bl&ots=BMtKvwsDCj&sig=eIXL7Q0CRpklPnU1Wt78hfcAHoY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WaiWU6T4GOny7AaAr4HIDQ&redir_esc=y) i'll be glad if you have a look at the test he did there - which I don't understand : if each core has 100 threads to work , why does in the first 10 seconds - there were only 13 threads used ?  why not more ? ( he did there synchronous operation which tie a thread)

Comment: (continue)... but still - he says that threadpool create 2 more threads each second. but why create threads if asp.net already have 100 threads READY TO GO !!!! ? can u have alook at it ?

Comment: Actually ASP.NET doesn't have 100 threads at start time. ThreadPood creates new threads when requested up to minWorkerThreads value. Then if there are still work to do and threads are not enough it will add new thread each half a second when needed.

Comment: no.  asp.net does have 100 threads per core at start time.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/RvJQ3.jpg ( this guy build iis core)

Comment: Try to check yourself by calling `ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads` and `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads` at application start time or when request is executed.

Comment: My friend , I already have. ive been working on it for the last 5 days. look here and see how initializations threads are diffrent and how asp.net does set 100 threads per core http://i.stack.imgur.com/vbQhD.jpg

Comment: `ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads` doesn't give you number of threads created in thread pool. It's a number of threads that it is possible to create. Try check you app memory footprint. Each allocated thread takes about 1MB in memory. I don't think you app consumes 1GB at start time.

Comment: if so , if i have 200 users who requests data from the server , they will wait a long time till threadpool will have enough threads( assuming prv threads still working)....

Comment: Exactly. You can set `minWorkerThread` to 25 for your 8 cores server if you know for sure that it will use it. But it is not recommended because if the load will fall down thread will still be in use but not that effective. Try read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx) article too.

Comment: Thank you  my friend. my mistake was missing the "max" word. I thout they are initially initialized to 100 threads. appraently they initialized to MAX 100 ( per core). however i still wonder how iis (8 core) takes care of  many many simultainously requests ( ~2 sec each) while growing its thread pool threads by 2 per second.....

Comment: Sure, I send good time digging IIS and understanding how it works. I think for that many requests IIS maintains other queue. AFAIR this was described in those two articles from Thomas Marquardt. (One you've mentioned in you question).

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN,

> the default maximum [number of threads in the ASP.net server pool] for
>   .NET 4.5 is 5,000

[Source](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)

Comment: please read it again. request != thread. asp.net sets 100 threads per core. this attribute is for async operations

Comment: @RoyiNamir, perhaps I misunderstand. .NET 4 in IIS 7 has 5000 max concurrent application pool threads per CPU, as reported on [this page of the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560842%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: 5000 max concurrent requsts ! not threads ! Again , thread != request. this is for async operations where a request doesnt tie a thread. (_The difference only matters when the requests are asynchronous (the request either has an asynchronous handler or a module in the pipeline completes asynchronously)._ read this excat line here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx